# Get specific node data in AciTree plugin

Tags: jquery, acitree

I have following JSON source for aciTree plugin and would like to retrieve value of the node `"tree-data"`. I don't see any specific function in the documentation. Any thoughts ?

```
[{
    "id": "-",
    "label": "100 - Environment",
    "inode": true,
    "open": false,
    "checkbox": false,
    "branch": [{
        "id": "M-CSP-HID-1301-01W8",
        "label": "100.10.10 Dangerous Fauna",
        "inode": true,
        "open": false,
        "checkbox": true,
        "tree-data": "M-CSP-HID-1301-01W8#^Dangerous Fauna#^Low",
        "branch": [{
            "id": "-",
            "label": "Coming into contact (ingestion, bites, stings, injection) with potentially dangerous animals that include - Invertebrate - Protozoa (one celled organisms - amoeba), Arachnids (Spiders, scorpions), Insects (mosquitoes, fire ants, bees), Crustaceans (Crabs), Annelids (Leeches), Echinoderms (Sea Urchin), Scyphozoa (Jelly Fish): Vertebrate - Fish (Shark, piranha, stingray), Amphibians (dart frogs), Mammals (Cows, Moose, Whales, etc.), Rodents (Rats, mice, etc.), Primates (Apes) , Reptiles (snakes, alligator, etc.), Birds (Raptors)",
            "checkbox": false
        }]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward,

```
 var itemData = api.itemData(item);
 tnode=itemData._nodedata;
```

> "tree-data" is renamed to _nodedata.